# Make API call before computed properties run Vuejs

Tags: vue.js

I am creating a vuejs application that need to fetch data from the backend using API. And the data will be populated using a computed properties and display it on the screen.

But I found that the computed properties will run before the data is fetched from the backend. This make the computed properties always return me an error. (Data not exists at the time computed properties is running)

Here is the example of my code.

```
<template>
  <!-- Populated data will be display here -->
  <div v-for="service in serviceList" :key="service"></div>
</template>

<script>
import { getServices } from "@/services/product.js";

export default {
  name: "Services",
  data() {
    return {
      services: null,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    async fetchService() {
      try {
        const response = await getServices();
        this.services = response.data;
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    },
  },
  computed: {
    serviceList() {
      // services will be populated here
      return this.services;
    },
  },
  created() {
    // Featch data from backend
    this.fetchService();
  },
};
</script>
```

Is there any ways to make my data ready before the computed properties is running?

Thank you.

Comment: Just want to understand the use case of `serviceList()` method in computed ? You can call this method inside try block and perform the manipulations in the data whatever you want.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the current code snippet there's no need to a computed property, just init the `services` with an empty array :

```js
  data() {
    return {
      services: [],
    };
  },
```

then use it in template :

```html
<div v-for="service in services" :key="service"></div>
```

You can format the response directly inside try block.

```
try {
    const response = await getServices();
    // format your response data here and then bind in the `this.services`
    this.services = response.data;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But the data fetched from API is not actually what I prefer. I need to format it using computed properties before display it out. (Above just the simplify version)

Comment: Do you have any ideas to handle this.

Comment: so just replace `null` by `[]`

Comment: @XinhaoKoh You can format that inside try block itself instead of as a computed property. I updated this answer.